# Springfox Swagger2 XML Configuration

Tags: xml, spring, swagger

I'm setting up Springfox Swagger 2 implementation in an existing Spring MVC project that uses XML-based configuration.

How would I declare an XML configuration for the configuration class below?

```
package com.company.util;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import springfox.documentation.builders.PathSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.builders.RequestHandlerSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.service.ApiInfo;
import springfox.documentation.service.Contact;
import springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket;
import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;

@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {

    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.company.controllers.api"))
            .paths(PathSelectors.regex("/api/.*"))
            .build()
            .apiInfo(custInfo());
    }

    public ApiInfo custInfo() {
       ApiInfo apiInfo = new ApiInfo(
               "Title", 
               "API Documentation", 
               "1.0",               
               "TOS",              
               new Contact("Contact", "https://www.company.com", "test@test.com"), 
               "license",      
               "https://www.license.com/"); //License URL

        return apiInfo;
    }
}
```

Comment: The above code works even in XML based configuration. Just make sure this file is in the package which is under component scan

Comment: Yes, I understand that.  However, I’m looking for the XML configuration that is equivalent to it.